# How to Map dynamically the properties of a JObject in C# using Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch.net

I want to map dynamically the properties inside a JObject in C# using Nest. 
The goal is to map every string field of the object as SearchAsYouType.
I thought about 3 ways of doing that that didn't work:

1. Use AutoMap and declare the attribute in the C# Class directly

```
public class Forfait
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [SearchAsYouType()] 
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class  Act
    {
        public JObject Entity;
    }
```

```
Forfait forfait = new Forfait()
            {
                Data = "data",
                Id = 99
            };
            Act act = new Act()
            {
                Entity = JObject.FromObject(forfait)
            };

            await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index", o => o
                .Map<Act>(m => m
                .AutoMap()
```

2.Use DynamicTemplates but i can't find SearchAsYouType in the Mapping, it seems that it doesn't exist in Nest 7.4.1 yet

```
await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index", o => o
                .Map<Act>(m => m
                .DynamicTemplates(d =>d
                    .DynamicTemplate("stringassearch",dt => dt
                        .Match("entity.*")
                        .MatchMappingType("string")
                        .Mapping(ma =>ma
                            .)))));
```

3.Use a Visitor to force every String to be a SearchAsYouType

```
public class EveryStringIsASearchAsYouTypePropertyVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
    {
        public override IProperty Visit(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                return new SearchAsYouTypeProperty();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index", o => o
                .Map<Act>(m => m
                .AutoMap(new EveryStringIsASearchAsYouTypePropertyVisitor(),2)
```

Everything failed

I have a feeling the solution is in the NEST.JsonNetSerializer to somehow make the settings used in the mapping apply inside the JObject but i couldn't find anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2.Use DynamicTemplates but i can't find SearchAsYouType in the Mapping, it seems that it doesn't exist in Nest 7.4.1 yet

You are right, looks like it's missing from `SingleMappingSelector`, but you can easily work around it with this extension class which will add support for `search_as_you_type` type.

```
static class MappingExtension
{
    public static IProperty SearchAsYouType<T>(this SingleMappingSelector<T> mappingSelector, 
        Func<SearchAsYouTypePropertyDescriptor<T>, ISearchAsYouTypeProperty> selector) where T : class
    => selector?.Invoke(new SearchAsYouTypePropertyDescriptor<T>());
}
```

and then you can create your dynamic template like follow

```
var createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index", o => o
    .Map<Act>(m => m
        .AutoMap<Act>()
        .DynamicTemplates(d => d
            .DynamicTemplate("stringassearch", dt => dt
                .PathMatch("entity.*")
                .MatchMappingType("string")
                .Mapping(ma => ma.SearchAsYouType(s => s))))));
```

Note, I have changed `Match(..)` to `PathMatch(..)` - I think this is what you need. Also, I had to change `Act` definition to

```
public class  Act
{
    public object Entity;
}
```

After indexing sample document this index mapping was created

```
{
  "index": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "stringassearch": {
            "path_match": "entity.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "search_as_you_type"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "entity": {
          "properties": {
            "data": {
              "type": "search_as_you_type",
              "max_shingle_size": 3
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4249) is the GH issue.

Hope that helps.